# python3 the way to write string into file in its entirety

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am a newbie in Python3.
I have a question in writing a string into a file.

The below string is what I tried to write into a file.

`ÀH \x10\x08\x81\x00` (in hex, c04820108810)

When I checked the file using `xxd` command, I could check there is a difference between the string and the file.

```
00000000: c380 4820 1008 c281 00                   ..H .....
```

This is code I wrote.

```
s = 'ÀH \x10\x08\x81\x00'
with open('test', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

The question is how can I write this string into file in its entirety.

Comment: Do you want to write this as binary? Then use `bytes`, not `str`: `s = b'ÀH \x10\x08\x81\x00'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to write binary data. In that case, you should use the [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) type instead of [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) as this gives you full control over the binary content of the sequence.

When dealing with strings, you have to take into account that Python will internally handle everything as UTF-8, so by the time you enter something like `À`, the file encoding will decide on what is actually entered. You can always `encode()` a string to look at its bytes:

```
>>> 'ÀH \x10\x08\x81\x00'.encode()
b'\xc3\x80H \x10\x08\xc2\x81\x00'
```

You can convert this to hex using the `binascii` module for a more readable hex string of those bytes:

```
>>> binascii.hexlify('ÀH \x10\x08\x81\x00'.encode())
b'c38048201008c28100'
```

As you can see, this is the same that was written to your file. So Python already does the correct thing. It’s just that the *input* is not what you want it to be.

So instead, use a bytes string and write to the file in binary mode:

```
# use a bytes string
s = b'\xc0\x48\x20\x10\x88\x10'

# open the file in binary mode
with open('test', 'bw') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Btw. if you look at the encoded string from the beginning, you can already see that you have a different encoding in mind than Python when you entered that string. You expected `À` to be `0xc0` in binary which is somewhat correct since that its Latin-1 representation. But when you [lookup its other representations](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c0/index.htm), you can see that in UTF-8, which is what Python uses by default, it is `0xc380` instead—which is again the value we got when encoding it in Python.

Comment: The strings is not static. In this case, the string was just shown as Latin-1 representation by chance. If it is dynamic, how can I convert the string to bytes like b'\xc0\x48\x20\x10\x88\x10'?

Comment: I showed you in the answer, you can call `.encode()` on the string to convert it to a bytes string. You can also specify a different encoding if you don’t want to use UTF-8, e.g. `'ÀH \x10\x08\x81\x00'.encode('latin-1')`. But it all depends on where your input comes from. If you are really handling binary here, it should never be inside of a decoded string.

Comment: I understood. Thank you so much. Your answer and comments are really helpful for me.

Answer (score -1):

You have to setup coding style to utf-8 and also use raw strings because you have \ escape characters. So add coding style and put r before your string to make it raw.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = r'ÀH \x10\x08\x81\x00'
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Comment: Python 3 is already UTF-8 by default, no need to specify a file encoding.